# Songs like Preludes, Book I, L117

Tags: classical-music

I have some of those random "top 99 essential" classical albums. One of the songs is Préludes, Book I, L 117  VIII. La Fille Aux Cheveux De Lin (The Girl With The Flaxen Hair), played by Peter Schmalfuss.  It's an incredibly beautiful piece of music, but knowing nothing about Classical music... are there other pieces "similar" to this?  Is Peter Schmalfuss' renditions typically like this?  Or is this most likely just one song, unique in itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The piece itself - La Fille Aux Cheveux De Lin (The Girl With The Flaxen Hair)  - is by Débussy, so other Préludes for piano by Débussy would certainly be in a similar style.  Débussy is usually categorised as an "impressionist" composer, so other impressionist composers such as Ravel or Satie, while not totally similar would have a similar idiom, and both of them composed music for the piano.  If you like piano music, Pascal Rogé is a noted interpreter of this style of music.  Obviously, hard to give a complete list in answer to your question, but I hope my answer gives enough pointers for you to investigate further.

Comment: Thank you!  That's very helpful, I'll start to explore Debussy and the other composers mentioned.  Much appreciated..